# Injecting arbitrary script tags into a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to embed a [StreamingVideoProvider](https://www.streamingvideoprovider.com/) video player into my React application but:

- I don't have direct access to the video URL
- I don't want to bypass their JS video player because it offers a lot of features like password-protection, subtitles and other features for which I haven't found any alternative (all other video hosting services who offer password protection don't let me create any number of passwords to protect each video)
- They don't offer any React component I can use directly

The only thing they provide me with is the following sort of embed code that normally goes into a simple HTML page:

```
<!--player code begin-->
<div id="svp_playerdrxtsr0w13c4" style="width:720px;height:810px;position:relative;"></div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="//play.streamingvideoprovider.com/js/dplayer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
<!--
var vars = {clip_id:"drxtsr0w13c4",transparent:"true",pause:"1",repeat:"",bg_color:"#ffffff",fs_mode:"2",no_controls:"",start_img:"0",start_volume:"34",close_button:"",brand_new_window:"1",auto_hide:"1",stretch_video:"",player_align:"NONE",offset_x:"0",offset_y:"0",player_color_ratio:0.6,skinAlpha:"50",colorBase:"#250864",colorIcon:"#ffffff",colorHighlight:"#7f54f8",direct:"false",is_responsive:"true",viewers_limit:0,cc_position:"bottom",cc_positionOffset:70,cc_multiplier:0.03,cc_textColor:"#ffffff",cc_textOutlineColor:"#ffffff",cc_bkgColor:"#000000",cc_bkgAlpha:0.1,aspect_ratio:"16:9",play_button:"1",play_button_style:"pulsing",sleek_player:"1",auto_play:"",auto_play_type:"unMute",floating_player:"none"};
var svp_player = new SVPDynamicPlayer("svp_playerdrxtsr0w13c4", "", "100%", "100%", {use_div:"svp_playerdrxtsr0w13c4",skin:"3"}, vars);
svp_player.execute();
//-->
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript! JavaScript is needed to display this video player!</noscript>
<!--player code end-->
```

Is it possible to write a component that lets me embed a video player like this into my React app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way would be [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) (please, read carefully). Other way would to refactor this into react component. React is just a way to render something and fire some side effects after. If you want to go this approach - read further.

First thing you do - add their player script to your html once (it is on third line). Next, create a component that will render your markup placement for player. You will pass `vars` as a props to component. Construct id for your placement from `props.clip_id` so you would be able to refer it into effect. Create effect that will initialize the player.

Here is a [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/La4ct7v0/1/). You will need to adapt it to your particaular needs. Probably you would want to perform cleanup or something else - for this you can store player instance in ref and manipulate it in other effects when props change, or perform cleanups.